# I forgot my Super User email, how do I recover my account?

Tags: discussion, stackoverflow

It seems to be a joke, but it isn't.

I had been using Mozilla Firefox as my primary browser until today. From now on, I'm planning to use Google Chrome as my default browser.

Weeks ago, I somehow logged in Super User for the first time via my Stack Overflow account in Firefox. Now I'm trying to log in in Chrome, but it asks my email address and I don't remember it.

When I enter my account in Firefox, I see that an email address of mine is listed there. (The same address shown for email subscription when I'm asking a new question.) But I cannot log in with that mail address. I tried several possible passwords, but non of them worked. I tried recovering my password, but it says "No account with that email was found".

What do you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your user profile on the main site ([here](https://superuser.com/users/95347/hkbattousai)) through FireFox. At the top right there should be two links, "edit" and "my logins". Click the latter to see which addresses are linked to your account.

You may also add another login method like your Google account, Facebook of Yahoo.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In the picture above, there was a different mail of mine was listed. But that one hadn't either worked when I tried password recovery. Anyway, I managed to recover my account by connecting over Facebook. It is strange that connecting over Google account didn't work. My displayed mail address was of my Google account. Is that the reason why connection over Google failed?

Comment: note that this only works if you are logged in to this account, of course...

Comment: @hkBattousai You may try to ask a moderator to unlink your google account so you can try to re-add it to your login methods.

Comment: @hkBattousai it looks like your account only has a Facebook login associated with it right now. If you want to be able to log in with your Google account you'll have to add it by clicking on the "add more logins" button.