# Gmail Blocked, Now How to login Gmail using credentials in stackoverflow?

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid, login

My gmail is blocked in my firm and I have my SO login with my gmail account, so can someone suggest how can use my same gmail account to login to SO?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you can log in from home, you can just add another OpenID provider. Follow the instructions in this post:

[I forgot my Super User email, how do I recover my account?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3299/i-forgot-my-super-user-email-how-do-i-recover-my-account)

See also: [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)